# how to fix the error: 'property initializers run before' self 'is available' in @FetchRequest

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have the following structure and in the @FetchRequest I get an error in the predicate, var 'nomAcuariL', I don't know how to solve this error, how do I initialize the property?

Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4zVq.jpg)

```
 import SwiftUI
    
    struct Llist: View {
        
        var nomAcuariL : String
        var parametres : Parametres
        
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
        
        @FetchRequest(entity: Parametres.entity(),sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Parametres.nomParametres, ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "nomParametres = %@", nomAcuariL)) var contactos: FetchedResults<Parametres>
    
        
        var body: some View {
            
            List{
                ForEach(contactos, id:\.self){ contact in
                    Text("\(contact.nomParametres ?? "")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59345830/12299030?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the instance member `nomAcuariL` in the FetchRequest because it has not been initialized yet. In other words, it does not exist when you try to initialize the FetchRequest. You will need to pass that value in to the fetch request by some object that already exists. Try using a class or struct that you can instantiate there that has the data, or simply use a literal string.

Comment: And how could I do it? I don't know how to do it

Comment: Using a shared ObservedObject comes to mind. Set up a singleton(essentially) class, put the data in it  and use that. However, the is a wholly different question.

Comment: you can't give an answer and say it is a wholly different question.  singleton is not the way to go here.  try using a dynamic predicate.  in .onAppear you can set contactos.nsPredicate = ...  you may need to DispatchQueue.main.async {} around it.