# Coredata dynamic filters (predicate) in SwiftUI

Tags: filter, core-data, swiftui

I found many tutorials pointing out how to create a dynamic filter in Swiftui and Coredata, but none solved my problem, which is to create an entity extension like:

```
extension Food {
    var myFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Food> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Food> = Food.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)
    }
}
```

because obviously I get the following error:

[image]

I would like to get the following result:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Food.myFetchRequest)
    var food: FetchedResults<Food>
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(food) { food in
                        NavigationLink(destination: EditFoodView(food: food)) {
                            HStack {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                                    Text(food.name!)
                                        .bold()

                                    Text("\(Int(food.calories))") + Text(" calories").foregroundColor(.red)
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                Text(calcTimeSince(date: food.date!))
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .italic()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteFood)
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
            }
            .navigationTitle("iCalories")
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
        }
    
    // Deletes food at the current offset
    private func deleteFood(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { food[$0] }
            .forEach(managedObjContext.delete)

            // Saves to our database
            DataController().save(context: managedObjContext)
        }
    }
}
```

How do I have to change `extension Food {` to make the code work?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59345830/12299030?

Comment: [Please avoid posting error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). You can improve your question by posting it as a text.

Comment: @Asperi Based on your answer I found this [post](https://dev.to/bsorrentino/swiftui-dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-32m8) which, with minor changes, solved my problem.