# CoreData how to fetch all child elements using a SwiftUI property wrapper

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I am building a File Manager app.

In this App the user can optionally select a Folder. And I am building now a SwiftUI view to show the files of the selected folder, or ALL files if there are no selection.

I do have the selected folder in a AppState class:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedFolder: Folder?
}
```

And I am trying to build my FileListView using a predicate to filter the Files with that selected Folder:

```
struct FileListView: View {

    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \File.order, ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "folder = %@", appState.selectedFolder), animation: .default)
    var fileList: FetchedResults<File>
    
    @EnvironmentObject
    var appState: AppState

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(fileList) {
                file in
                Text(file.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However that Predicate does not work as expected and I get the following compilation error:

> Cannot use instance member 'appState' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI FetchRequest predicate with data from an ObservedObject causes property initialisers run before self is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74210076/swiftui-fetchrequest-predicate-with-data-from-an-observedobject-causes-property)

Comment: Then again, maybe you don't need a FetchRequest at all here. Do you have a relationship between Folder and File in your Core Data model?